# Finding first digit index in Python loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, digits

```
found = False
position = 0

while not found and position < len(inputString):
    if inputString[position].isdigit():
        found = True
    else:
        position += 1

if found:
    print('first digit is at position', position)
else:
    print('There are no digits in the string')
```

This is a simple program I found that deals with finding the first digit in an inputted string. Something I am having trouble understanding is...

`if inputString[position].isdigit(): 
    found = True`

What exactly does this expression state, specifically the `inputString[position]` part. Are we looking for the position/index value of the first digit and then breaking the loop into the print statement below?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why not? In the next iteration, the condition becomes false, as found becomes true, and the loop breaks

Comment: Yes, it iterates through the string and as soon as it gets a digit it returns.

Comment: correct. I didn't see that. Which is a red flag for "don't use a while loop for this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are we looking for the position/index value of the first digit and
>   then breaking the loop into the print statement below?

Yes, that's true. It breaks because once a digit is found, in the next iteration `while not found` condition will give `while False` and break the `while` loop. Worth noting `and` short-circuits, so the second condition is not even evaluated.

If a digit is not found, `position` increments until it is equal to `len(inputString)`, at which point the `while` loop breaks via the second condition, i.e. `position < len(inputString)`.

---

A more Pythonic / idiomiatic way to write your `while` loop is via `for` loop and `enumerate`:

```
for idx, val in enumerate(inputString, 1):
    if val.isdigit():
        position = idx
        break
else:
    position = 0

if position:
    print('first digit is at position', position)
else:
    print('There are no digits in the string')
```

Notice, in this solution, since we start counting from 1, we can take advantage of the fact if a digit is found it must be "Truthy", i.e. non-zero. Therefore, we don't need an extra `found` variable.

Comment: Would you think it's a bit more convenient to make position equal to 1 instead of 0 to not confuse the user (since compilers count from 0)?

Comment: That's a matter of preference. You can start from 1, then check `position <= len(inputString)`. Entirely up to you. Both methods are equally readable, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The `position` is your iteration variable like in a `for` loop. So every time you don't find a digit you go to the next char in the string.

The `inputString[position]` reads what stands the `position`'s place in the string. So if your string is `abcdefg` then `inputString[2]= c` (not `b` since python starts counting from 0).

The `.isdigit()` then looks if at this position is a digit. If it is a digit, then `found = True` and the while loop is stopped. (Else it continues.)

After the loop ends, the function prints one of the two messages depending on if there was a digit in the `inputString`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the value of `inputString` at the position, `position`. `position` is first initialized as zero, and then it while loops each position (notice `position += 1`) to see if it `.isdigit()`.

Answer (score 0):

A string in python can be used as an sequence, which means you can use an index to access its elements. For example:
`"Victor"[0]` is V.

So in your example you are retrieving one of the elements (characters) of the string. The function `isdigit()` is a string method which can check if that character is a digit.

Comment: Hi @VictorVasiliev, welcome to stackoverflow! Unfortunately there are some problems with your answer. Even though you are generally correct, you are misusing several terms. I will edit your text to make it more technically correct.

Answer (score 0):

`inputString[position]` gives the character at position in inputString. For example, if inputString = "Foobar" and position = 3, inputString[position] = "b".

When we find a digit this way, then found turns True, and the evaluation condition of the while becomes False. The program leaves the loop and prints.

Answer (score 0):

Gather all the indexes of possible digits, if the list is not empty print the `0` index, else if the list is empty print your no digits statement.

```
lst = [i for i, v in enumerate(s) if v.isdigit()]
if len(lst):
    print(f'First digit is at postion {lst[0]}')
else:
    print('There are no digits in the string.')
```